# add average column into same table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, average

I have a table like:
[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtJYA.png)
And I need to add a column to that table as average delivery time
[avr_del_time column added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avk9o.png)
My code is:

```
SELECT a.vendor, a.part_nr, a.delivery_time, b.avr_del_time
FROM  Table1 a
INNER JOIN (SELECT AVG(delivery_time) AS avr_del_time FROM Table1 GROUP BY vendor, part_nr) b
ON a.vendor = b.vendor, a.part_nr=b.part_nr
```

please guide me...

Answer (score 2):

Your query is on the right track.  You just need to fix up the SQL mistakes:

```
SELECT a.vendor, a.part_nr, a.delivery_time, b.avr_del_time
FROM Table1 as a INNER JOIN
      (SELECT  vendor, part_nr, AVG(delivery_time) AS avr_del_time
       FROM Table1
       GROUP BY vendor, part_nr
     ) as b
     ON a.vendor = b.vendor AND a.part_nr = b.part_nr;
```

Notes:

- In the `GROUP BY` subquery, you need the keys in the `SELECT`.
- You have a comma in the `ON` condition; it should be `AND`.
- I would suggest that you use table aliases that are abbreviations for the table names.

Answer (score 1):

Don't see any issue with your posted code except the `JOIN ON` condition which should

```
ON a.vendor = b.vendor
AND a.part_nr=b.part_nr // OR condition can as well be based on requirement
```

Also since it's a computed value, no point in adding a separate column to your table rather have that column in your display result while fetching from table

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the joined fields in the subquery or the join won't work

```
SELECT a.vendor, a.part_nr, a.delivery_time, b.avr_del_time
FROM  Table1 a
INNER JOIN (SELECT Vendor, 
                   part_nr, 
                   AVG(delivery_time) AS avr_del_time 
            FROM Table1 
            GROUP BY vendor, part_nr) b
ON a.vendor = b.vendor and a.part_nr=b.part_nr
```